# How to add bitbucket private Git repository to AOSP?

Tags: android, git, android-source, repo

**my bitbucket ssh url:** 
`git@bitbucket.org:MY_USERNAME/PROJECT_NAME.git`

**.repo/local_manifests/manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote name="my_remote" fetch="git@bitbucket.org:MY_USERNAME/" />  
  <project path="packages/apps/PROJECT_NAME" name="PROJECT_NAME" remote="my_remote" revision="master" />
</manifest>
```

I get this error after `repo sync`:

```
Fetching projects:  99% (409/413)  fatal: remote error: Git repository not found
error: Cannot fetch PROJECT_NAME

error: Exited sync due to fetch errors
```

I have all the rights of reading/writing into the bitbucket repository.

Comment: Did you try to put git:// prefix for the fetch?

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
<remote name="my_remote" fetch="ssh://git@bitbucket.org/MY_USERNAME"/>
```

From the BitBucket [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket), section "Repository URL formats by connection protocol"

Answer (score 0):

I know we used to use some toolchains in our manifest hosted on BitBucket, but I think due to bitbucket change or repo tool change we had to stop. So I looked back at one of my manifests history, and found it here: https://github.com/sudosurootdev/platform_manifest/blob/edcde119f3b8f865582fdaa368e9cc7a3b877f3c/default.xml#L502 the remote was from here: https://github.com/sudosurootdev/platform_manifest/blob/edcde119f3b8f865582fdaa368e9cc7a3b877f3c/default.xml#L15 ...on bitbucket. I would agree with the comment though, try the `git://` prefix... however if that doesn't work you may have to copy the project over to Github, which is what we ended up doing.